# Can you use React Native RefreshControl without hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I want to use [RefreshControl](https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol) in my React Native app, but the demo implementation in their docs uses hooks, which I'm not using in my app. When I copy paste the demo code, I get the error `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`. Is there a way for me to use this library without converting my component to a function component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RefreshControl` in a class-based component and therefore avoid hooks. Here is an example:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ListView, RefreshControl, Text } from 'react-native'


class RefreshControlExample extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      refreshing: false,
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2 }),
      cars : [
        {name:'BMW',color:'White'},
        {name:'Mercedes',color:'Green'}
      ]
    }
  }

   componentWillMount(){
     this.setState({ dataSource:
       this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.cars) })
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <ListView
          refreshControl={this._refreshControl()}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(car) => this._renderListView(car)}>
        </ListView>
      </View>
    )
  }

  _renderListView(car){
    return(
      <View style={styles.listView}>
        <Text>{car.name}</Text>
        <Text>{car.color}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  _refreshControl(){
    return (
      <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={()=>this._refreshListView()} />
    )
  }

  _refreshListView(){
    //Start Rendering Spinner
    this.setState({refreshing:true})
    this.state.cars.push(
      {name:'Fusion',color:'Black'},
      {name:'Yaris',color:'Blue'}
    )
    //Updating the dataSource with new data
    this.setState({ dataSource:
        this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.cars) })
    this.setState({refreshing:false}) //Stop Rendering Spinner
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  listView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    marginTop:10,
    marginRight:10,
    marginLeft:10,
    padding:10,
    borderWidth:.5,
    borderColor:'#dddddd',
    height:70
  }

})

export default RefreshControlExample;
```